# MacOS, how to get folder size (physical size on disk)

Tags: macos, apfs

Ok so I have a large folder on disk see the image below

[image]

You can see it says the size of the folder is 8.46GB however this is mostly source code, and I think file system will be using file compression under the hood. I'd expect this folder to compress very well, so my question is this. "How can I find out how much actual physical space this folder is using?"

Thanks

Comment: Not sure APFS already supports compression, even with Mojave.

Comment: I think that what you are seeing is correct (i.e. 9.73 GB). No file compression in APFS.  I would expect source code (with lots of small files) to be relatively inefficient due to lots of upwards rounding.  And this is reflected in your numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You should go to the terminal and from the terminal cd to the folder you want to get the size of. Once there type: `du -h`. The last number it prints is the directory size.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that for some time now Apple abandoned using base-2 calculations in Finder and now use base-10, while most of the BSD command line utilities still use base-2 calculations.

Comment: The final line in du -h is rounded to a whole number of GB.  So this doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

On my macOS 14.3 system, `du` supports a `-A` option that displays the apparent size instead of disk usage. HFS+ and APFS support transparent compression, which you can see with the third-party [`afsctool`](https://github.com/RJVB/afsctool).

```
$ cd /Applications/Playgrounds.app
$ du -Acsk .
1823119 .
1823119 total

$ du -csk .
686872  .
686872  total

$ afsctool -v .
/Applications/Playgrounds.app/.:
Number of HFS+/APFS compressed files: 16872
Total number of files: 19373
Total number of folders: 3985
Total number of items (number of files + number of folders): 23358
Folder size (uncompressed; reported size by Mac OS 10.6+ Finder): 1858926255 bytes / 1.91 GB (gigabytes, base-10)
Folder size (compressed): 702022959 bytes / 677.9 MiB
Compression savings: 62.2% over 16872 of 19373 files
Approximate total folder size (files + file overhead + folder overhead): 711847336 bytes / 678.9 MiB
```